# Directory Chooser in HTML page (JS, or ExtJs)

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

How can I create a directory chooser? I know that there are a large number of same problems, and I also know that there is:

```
<input type="file" webkitdirectory directory />
```

It works fine with chrome, but doesn't work with Firefox. Is there any solutions? In firefox it opens file chooser dialog, and I can't choose directory, only file.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work in Firefox? What happens?

Comment: in firefox it opens file chooser dialog, and I can't choose directory, only file.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox does not support this.
Some information here: [Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/959352)

Answer (score 0):

There's no standards recommendation for this feature (the "directory" attribute) and so Firefox hasn't implemented it:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=782233

I think the general feeling is that being able to select multiple files will often give you what you need here, and all modern desktop browsers support that:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-multiple

You have also consider - even if you could choose a directory from the picker, how would that look in the form post and server-side processing?

So the conclusion is that if you need Firefox support you're pretty much out of luck, and there are multiple reasons why that seems unlikely to change.